# How do I get a return value from a signal handler in C?

Tags: c, signals

I read a similar question in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23076909/return-value-of-signal) link but it didn't solve my problem so apologies for the repeat question.

I have the following code that basically receives Ctrl+C and Ctrl+Z when the program is executed but I would like for the 2 signal handler functions to return 1 when it receives the signals from terminal.

The link said something about using typedef and being fairly new to C I don't know how to implement that in the code I have.

Here's the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

/* Signal Handler for SIGINT */
void sigintHandler(int sig_num) {

    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
    printf("\n Cannot be terminated using Ctrl+C \n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

/* Signal Handler for SIGTSTP */
void sigtstpHandler(int sig_num) {  
    signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstpHandler);
    printf("\tCtrl+z received\n");  
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main (void) {

    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
    signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstpHandler); 

    while(1) {}  //infinite loop.
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your time/help.

EDIT : I'd like for the 2 signal handler functions that are currently

```
    void sigintHandler(int sig_num)
    void sigtstpHandler(int sig_num)
```

to return 1 instead of just void. So that I can do something like

```
int sigIntReturn = signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
```

in the main function.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Return 1 to what?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry. I added an edit to my question. Please have a read.

Comment: The standard mandates `void`. You cannot return a value. Use a (`volatile`) global variable instead (somewhat like `errno`).

Comment: You cannot return a value from a signal handler, since **there is no caller** to recieve it. The only thing that could possibly help you is one of the `wait()` functions. Also: SIGSTOP (and SIGKILL) cannot be caught)

Comment: `signal` does not even send a signal - it just sets up the handling of a signal. `kill` sends a signal.

Answer (score 0):

Signal handler is like an interrupt and does not return to anyone. The link you posted talks about returning value while setting the signal handler and not about signal handler returning value (Note that `signal` is just setting signal handler).

You can however do something similar to the following to return from main whenever the signal happens.

```
volatile int g_flag = 0;
void sigintHandler(int sig_num) {

    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);

    /* Not safe to use these functions in a signal handler */
    printf("\n Cannot be terminated using Ctrl+C \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    g_flag = 1;
}

int main (void) {

    signal(SIGINT, sigintHandler);
    signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstpHandler); 

    while(g_flag == 0) {}  //infinite loop.
    return g_flag;
}
```

Please note that it is a busy loop in main which is not recommended. You an use something like eventfd to signal.

Comment: This won't work. Components other than the compiler are free to optimize the `while` loop to not check `g_flag` (even if it's `volatile`). You need to use a `sig_atomic_t` or equivalent -- see the C standard.

Comment: Also, you can't use a pthread conditional wait since none of those functions are signal safe.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. But any reference why you say while loop is optimized even if declared volatile? Yes, we cannot use conditional wait as it uses mutex. Something like eventfd is good.

Comment: @user1969104 This is a great response and I'm supposed to be implementing conditional pthreads later on but in our course at least we are discouraged from using global variables. Would you be able to explain a little further how I could adapt the code for conditional pthreads?

Comment: @user100000 — just about the only communication mechanism available to signal handlers is via global variables.  If you can't use them, don't do signal handling.  It is pretty much as simple as that   Note that many functions are not a sync-signal safe. In particular, the standard I/o functions are not.

Comment: It's what the C standard says. I can't think of any way it could fail, but you never know what future hardware might do.

Comment: @user100000, as David pointed out, conditional variable may not be safe in the signal handler. You may want to read eventfd. Just call eventfd(...) in main, and read(..) instead of while loop. From signal handler, call write(...). You can look into examples of eventfd.

Comment: @user1969104 thank you for the information. I'll take a look at what you suggested.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Can you please provide a more specific reference to help me understand it better. I assume that compiler will not optimize volatile as mentioned in http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124222941.htm. Do you mean a future processor hardware could optimize the execution? Doesn't it mean the processor is not behaving as expected?

Comment: @user1969104 It means the processor is not behaving as you expected. But what in the C standard gives you the right to expect that? You have the right to expect that the C compiler will generate code that makes the CPU execute in a way that the results comply with the requirements of the C standard and that's it. C99 says "If the signal occurs other than as the result of calling the `abort` or `raise` function, the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object with static storage duration other than by assigning a value to an object declared as `volatile sig_atomic_t`[.]"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Yes, because older C standards did not concern about threads in the first place and I have no right to assume that the write in one thread is visible in another thread unless synchronized explicitly.  But much legacy C code used this logic, and I believe compilers ensure this visibility from signal handlers, regardless of whether you declare it sig_atomic_t. May be I am wrong.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz And also, I hope that as soon as we add eventfd synchronization, the kind of execution optimization that you think as a possibility, may not be there.

Comment: @user1969104 C99's `sig_atomic_t` type is guaranteed to be atomic in the context of signal handlers (i.e. no "half" updates). That means it can be any type on an implementation as long 
as its properties are guaranteed. For example, on my 64-bit Linux `sig_atomic_t` is typedef'ed to `int`. But on a different architecture, it may be typedef'ed
to something else -- that's an implementation's choice provided whatever the type they choose guarantees the semantics required for `sig_atomic_t`. Regardless of `int` works or not, there's no reason to use `int` when `sig_atomic_t` is available.